# Prove equality with cross products using Einstein notation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, index-notation

Notice that throughout this question I will be using Einstein's summation notation.

Let $v(x):\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a vector field and define

$$2\mathbb{W}(v) = \nabla v - \nabla v^T$$

where

$$\nabla v = \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}e_i \otimes e_j$$

and where $$a \otimes b$$ is the matrix where the entry $(i,j)$ is $a_i b_j$.

I am asked to show

$$2\mathbb{W}(v)(x - x_0) = (\nabla \times v) \times (x-x_0)$$

If I do it component-wise, I am able to do it with no problem. Because for this course we have been using Einstein's summation notation a lot, I decided to try and do it myself. For the LHS I got to

$$2\mathbb{W}(v)(x - x_0) = \left(\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j} - \frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i} \right)(x-x_0)_je_i$$

which agrees with my result when I did everything component by component.

[Write $d = (x-x_0)$ for the sake of brevity].
For the triple product, I used the relation $(\nabla \times v)\times d = (d\cdot \nabla)v - \nabla (d\cdot v)$ where I got

$$(d\cdot \nabla)v = d_j\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}e_i $$

and

$$\nabla(d\cdot v) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(d_jv_j)e_i =  \left(\frac{\partial d_j}{\partial x_i}v_j + d_j\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i} \right)e_i$$

which, when put together, yields

$$\left(\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j} - \frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i}\right)d_je_i - \frac{\partial d_j}{\partial x_i}v_j e_i$$

which has that extra $\frac{\partial d_j}{\partial x_i}v_j e_i$... I have no idea where my mistake is! Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is $\nabla\times A\times B$?  Is it $(\nabla\times A)\times B$ or $\nabla\times(A\times B)$ or something else?

Comment: @user10354138 it is $(\nabla \times A) \times B$, I edited the question to include the parenthesis I had forgotten.

Comment: The mistake is using $x$ for two different things, the argument of $v$ (and $\nabla$) and the $x-x_0$.  Use separate variables for them and only impose equality at the end.